# Create custom rspec variable like response for controller specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, specs

I want to create a custom variable similar to `response` object that should only be available in `controller specs`. I noticed that rspec supports [filters](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/hooks/filters) which are before/after hooks which means I can create instance variables with them to be used later. But `response` object feels and works more like a `let` variable that is lazily evaluated. Also, controller specs support `assign` method that can accept arguments.
Does rspec support any way to create similar methods to be used with a specific type of spec?

Note: I don't need to support anything below rspec 3.0.

Comment: Maybe post what you are trying to test and we can be of more assistance from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this by creating a module with your function and then including that in your RSpec configure block. You can control the types of specs where this should be available as a second parameter when you include the module:

```
module ControllerSpecHelpers
  def something
    'fubar2000'
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ControllerSpecHelpers, type: :controller
end

RSpec.describe BlahController, type: :controller do
  it 'should be possible to use the `something` helper in a controller spec' do
    expect(something).to eq('fubar2000')
  end
end
```